# Question about Theorem 14.8 in Rudin's R&C analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

In the proof of Theorem 14.8 in Rudin's real and complex analysis, which is

> Every simply connected region $\Omega$ in the plane (other than the plane itself) is conformally equivalent to the open unit disc $U$,

while proving $\sum$, the class of all $\psi \in H(\Omega)$ which are one-to-one in $\Omega$ and which map $\Omega$ into $U$, is not empty,
he choose $\varphi \in H(\Omega)$ which is one-to-one and is an open mapping, so that $\varphi(\Omega)$ contains a disc $D(a;r)$ with $0 <r <|a|$. Then he said the disc $D(-a;r)$ fails to intersect $\varphi(\Omega)$.

But I can't see why this happens. Like what if $\varphi(\Omega)$ is a ball with center at $0$ and radius $|a| + 2r$?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this he has proved that $\phi(z_1)=-\phi(z_2)$ cannot happen for distinct points  $z_1$ and $z_2$. Now suppose $D(-a,r)\cap \phi(\Omega)$ consatin a point $z$. Then there exists $c \in \Omega$ such that $z=\phi (c)$. Since $|z+a| <r$ it follows that $-z \in D(a,r)$. So $-z\in \phi(\Omega)$. If $-z=\phi \zeta)$ ($\zeta \in \Omega$) it follows that $\phi (\zeta) =-\phi (c)$.  But this is a contradiction. Note that $-z=z$ would imply $z=0$ and $|a|=|z+a|<r$ a contradiction to $0<r<|a|$.